# Find the length of curve using the integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, parametric

Find the length of curve $$x(t)=1+2\cos(t)+\cos(2t)$$
$$y(t)=2\sin(t)+\sin(2t)$$

$$0<t<2π$$

I actually couldn't get the integral after writing the equation..

edit:sorry it must be 2π, not π

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know how to set up a parametric integral?

Comment: Arc length: $$s=\int_{0}^{t}{\sqrt{\dot{x}(t)^2 + \dot{y}(t)^2}\mathrm{d}t}$$

Comment: It's not a line

Comment: actually I found at the last from 0 to 2π sqrt(cos(2t))dt integral .. and didn't find the result

Comment: sorry it's a curve really sorry

Answer (score 0):

Let $z:=x+iy=1+2e^{it}+e^{2it}$ so$$\begin{align}ds&=\sqrt{\dot{z}\dot{z}^\ast}dt\\&=\sqrt{(2ie^{it}+2ie^{2it})(-2ie^{-it}-2ie^{-2it})}dt\\&=2\sqrt{(1+e^{it})(1+e^{-it})}dt\\&=2\sqrt{2(1+\cos t)}dt\\&=|4\cos\tfrac{t}{2}|dt.\end{align}$$So the arclength is$$\begin{align}\int_0^{2\pi}4|\cos\tfrac{t}{2}dt|&=\int_0^{\pi}8\cos\tfrac{t}{2}dt\\&=\left[16\sin\tfrac{t}{2}\right]_0^\pi\\&=16.\end{align}$$

Comment: oh god interesting approach to solve the arclength. from the usual way, I found from 0 to 2π sqrt(cos(2t)) integral but didn't find..

Comment: if it is from 0 to 2π , the result is zero..what does it mean?

Comment: @bradd I've edited the answer to reflect the updated integration limits. You need to integrate something non-negative to get the arclength, but when the upper limit was $\pi$ I didn't need modulus signs.